# jsp check box mulitple retaining the value after submiting

Tags: jsp

How to use multiple checkbox values to retian it values here is the code

How to retain values (i.e checked status) when submit button is click

Comment: Where is the code? What problem are you facing explain more about it this 2lines doesn't help much?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed/write value using EL expression:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkOne" value="${param.chkOne}" />
```